# Haskell return single tuple after recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, tuples

I was playing around with .bmp images and ascii art, and came across an issue regarding pattern matching and recursion with a tuple.

The function needs to simply convert the list of words to integers.. While carrying the height and width without change. My attempt:

```
convertToIntegers :: ([GHC.Word.Word8], Integer, Integer) -> ([Integer], Integer, Integer)
convertToIntegers ([], x, y) =  ([], x, y)
convertToIntegers ((a:as), x, y) = ( toInteger a : convertToIntegers (as, x, y), x, y)
```

Obviously, this doesn't work and returns a type error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[Integer]' with actual type `([Integer], Integer, Integer)'

In the return type of a call of `convertToIntegers' 
In the second argument of `(:)', namely `convertToIntegers (as, x, y)'
In the expression: toInteger a : convertToIntegers (as, x, y)
```

It seems like it should be simple, and I can accomplish it by splitting it up and using a helper function. In trying to figure this out, I tried the following:

```
convertToIntegers :: ([GHC.Word.Word8], Int, Int) -> [Integer]
convertToIntegers ([], x, y) =  []
convertToIntegers ((a:as), x, y) = toInteger a : convertToIntegers (as, x, y)
```

This works fine. So the issue is that I simply don't know how to return a single tuple while manipulating a list inside of it. It's really bugging me, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use map?

```
convertToIntegers :: ([GHC.Word.Word8], Integer, Integer) -> ([Integer], Integer, Integer)
convertToIntegers (as, x, y) = (map toInteger as, x, y)
```

Edit:

Your main issue is that you have an actual bug here:

```
( toInteger a : convertToIntegers (as, x, y), x, y)
                                    ^  ^  ^
```

You are returning a tuple as the first argument of another tuple, in the type signature you are claiming to be returning a list of integers. If you didn't want to use map, you could write it like this:

```
convertToIntegers :: ([GHC.Word.Word8], Integer, Integer) -> ([Integer], Integer, Integer)
convertToIntegers (as, x, y) = (convertWords as, x, y)
    where
        convertWords [] = []
        convertWords (z:zs) = toInteger z : convertWords zs
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could do multiple pattern matching in a where clause, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to code this use pattern is with `let`:

```
convertToIntegers :: ([GHC.Word.Word8], Integer, Integer) -> ([Integer], Integer, Integer)
convertToIntegers ([], x, y) =  ([], x, y)
convertToIntegers ((a:as), x, y) = let (rs, x2, y2) = convertToIntegers (as, x, y)
                                   in  (toInteger a : rs, x2, y2)
```

Haskell's `let` is recursive; if you'd use `x,y` on both sides of the definition inside `let`, you'd shadow the outer names `x,y` (block the access to them). This way the `x,y` on the RHS of the equation refer to the outer arguments `x,y`, and `x2,y2` on the LHS are used to pass along the values returned from the inner function call.

This doesn't mean that this call is made *before* the values are returned. Quite the contrary, because of Haskell's laziness, first the return value (a triple) is constructed, with holes, `(_1, _2, _3)` and only when those holes will be accessed this will trigger the further evaluation according to the definition, with `_1 = toInteger a : rs`, `_2 = x2`, `_3 = y2`. So if that access is `head _1`, no function call will be triggered yet.